# Implementing tree in a database with child having more than one parent

Tags: database, data-structures, tree

I've table with fields Id,Name,ParentId(Id) & Leaf. I want to model tree like structure where child/element with Leaf=1 can have more than more parent. How can I model this situation in this table or do I need an extra table to handle this thing. I want this modelling for implementing Tags like in Stack overflow.

Comment: FYI - Tags on [so] are **not** modelled as a tree.

Comment: I've just mentioned it.

Comment: Only elements with `Leaf=1` will be able to have multiple parents? Or all of them?

Comment: element with Leaf=1 can have multiple parents

Comment: I think you can manage this better as a graph.

Comment: I need some mechanism to save it to a database

Answer (score 0):

You'll need another table, unless "more than one parent" has a smallish upper limit, in which case you can add `ParentID` fields for the number of possible parents, but this is not recommended.

You appear to have a many-to-many relationship. This can be modelled as below:

```
Entity table
ID (Primary Key)
... - other entity fields

Parents table
ChildID  (Foreign Key - Entity.ID)
ParentID (Foreign Key - Entity.ID)
```

The `Leaf=1` entities being the only ones allowed to have multiple parents is a constraint that is best handled on a code level, or possibly with database triggers.

It doesn't seem possible to enforce this directly without creating **another** table (a third one) (which will contain all entities with `Leaf=1`, either linking to an `Entity` entry or having the row defined only there, though I would not advise either - it's messy and not the type of constraint you design your database around).